# CAN bus port access via socket; non-blocking solution needed

Tags: qt, sockets, qml, can-bus

I've got an application where I will be using a standalone C programming to read a CAN bus port with a socket. The user interface on this is Qt/QML code. I would like to use a non-blocking approach to call the bin program and either return nothing or return a string of the CAN packet.

The application will be low speed (just monitoring key presses, etc) so speed is not an issue. The current approach involves writing data from the socket program to a file, then having ANOTHER C program take the file and echo the string back to QML. UGH! Seems very messy. A simple Go/NoGo call would be easier. Here's the code I've got so far.

Thanks for any comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <linux/can.h>
#include <linux/can/raw.h>

//  Returns 0 if no errors, > 0 if errors found
int main(void) {

    struct ifreq ifr;
    struct can_frame frame;
    struct sockaddr_can addr;

    int s;                          // CAN socket descriptor
    int nbytes;                     // Number of bytes read from CAN socket

    char run_daemon = 0;            // Set to 1 to run as a daemon process
    char show_errors = 0;           // Set to 1 to print errors
    char *ifname = "can0";          // Define the CAN driver for use

    if (run_daemon)                 // Skip the daemon call if not enabled
        daemon(1,1);

    if ((s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW)) < 0) {
    if (show_errors)
        perror("Error while opening RAW socket");
    return 1;
    }

strcpy (ifr.ifr_name, ifname);
ioctl(s, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);

addr.can_family  = AF_CAN;
addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;


if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
    if (show_errors)
        perror("Error in socket bind");
    return 2;
    }

//  Loop here for daemon process
while (1) {

// Read CAN frame data
    nbytes = read(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));

// If data is ready, process it
    if (nbytes > 0) {

    // Print all relevent frame data to QML
       printf("%d ",frame.can_id);
       printf("%d ",frame.can_dlc);

       if(frame.can_dlc>0)  printf("%d ",frame.data[0]);
       if(frame.can_dlc>1)  printf("%d ",frame.data[1]);
       if(frame.can_dlc>2)  printf("%d ",frame.data[2]);
       if(frame.can_dlc>3)  printf("%d ",frame.data[3]);
       if(frame.can_dlc>4)  printf("%d ",frame.data[4]);
       if(frame.can_dlc>5)  printf("%d ",frame.data[5]);
       if(frame.can_dlc>6)  printf("%d ",frame.data[6]);
       if(frame.can_dlc>7)  printf("%d ",frame.data[7]);

       printf("\n");
       }

    if (!run_daemon) {      // Exit if daemon is not running
        close(s);           // Close the CAN socket
        return 0;
        }
    }
return 0;            // Should never get here !!!
}
```

Comment: What prevents you from using `QProcess` and its asynchronous interface to get notified whenever the CAN-speaking binary outputs some data? It's non-blocking by design.

Comment: This code was here before, and I've got a lot more to write for other sections. I wanted to make some minor change to this instead of writing it from new and getting that to work. I figured a few lines in the right spot should do it here.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand what you are asking for. Same as @KubaOber my suggestion would have been to run the program through `QProcess`. The program will just continue as is, reading in a tight loop, the process object will emit signals asynchronously when data arrives.

Comment: My original thought was that the CAN read call from QML would either immediately return the read packet as a string, or return nothing. Either way it would allow the QML to continue. I will investigate using QProcess on this also.

Comment: I'm working on adding the following. I read this as setting the socket as non-blocking? I'll test this out.
    int flags fcntl(socket, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl (socket, F_SETFL, flags | _NONBLOCK);

Comment: No luck so far... I changed the 2nd parameter on the ioctl call to FIONBIO and now the program crashes in the bind() call !!!